# "The name 'modToSend' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#

I have this simple piece of coding in my Homecontroller.cs, but I receive the error message on the last line, saying "The name 'modToSend' does not exist in the current context". How is that possible? Only in the last line is it not known????

```
public class HomeController : Controller, IDisposable
{
    private MvcEShop2.WcfEshop2Service.Eshop2ServiceClient proxy = null;

    private String GetDuration(DateTime startdatum, DateTime einddatum)
    {
        String maand1 = startdatum.Month.ToString("MMMM");
        String maand2 = einddatum.Month.ToString("MMMM");
        String duration = "";
        if (maand1 == maand2)
        {
            duration = startdatum.Day.ToString()
                + " - " + einddatum.Day.ToString()
                + " " + maand1
                + " " + startdatum.Year.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            duration = startdatum.Day.ToString()
                + startdatum.Month.ToString("MMMM")
                + " - " + einddatum.Day.ToString()
                + " " + einddatum.Month.ToString("MMMM")
                + " " + startdatum.Year.ToString();
        }
        return duration;
    }


    public HomeController()
     {
         proxy = new MvcEShop2.WcfEshop2Service.Eshop2ServiceClient();
     }

    struct EventStruct
    {
        public SEvent Event { get; set; }
        public String Duration { get; set; }
    };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SEvent> modFromWcf = proxy.GetAllEventsByPeriod(@System.DateTime.Now.Year, @System.DateTime.Now.Year + 1, "EN").ToList();
        List<EventStruct> modTosend = new List<EventStruct>();
        foreach (SEvent item in modFromWcf)
        {
            EventStruct ES;
            ES.Event = item;
            ES.Duration = GetDuration(item.StartDate ,item.EndDate);
            modTosend.Add(ES);
        };

        return View("Index", modToSend);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's a direct copy & paste from your code, check the case of the 'S' in your parameter to the View being returned.